# Angular 6 app with libraries : keep subprojects version in sync

Tags: angular, npm

I am building npm libraries to use with angular 6 projects. I have followed this article : https://blog.angularindepth.com/creating-a-library-in-angular-6-part-2-6e2bc1e14121

I have a root app that hosts all my libraries (as subprojects) and I would like to handle automaticaly the version numbers. For example, by using `npm version from-git`, it will update the version, but how can I replicate this version number to sub-projects before publishing them to my private registry ?